# Notify from c++ to UI in iOS app

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, audio

I am developing an audio generator on iOS 7 using Audio Units and rendering the samples in a cpp file. My problem is that I need to notify the output volume to the UI which is calculated in c++, during the rendering.

How could I achieve that? If I can call an objective C method from the cpp file, it would be enough.

Comment: You can compile your code as Objective-C++ - the simplest way is to rename your .cpp as .mm. It will then compile properly and you can (for the most part) mix Objective-C and C++ however you like.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Will that make things different to the cpp code? I mean, maybe the code execution will be slower if I compile the cpp code as Objective-C++... Are there any other drawbacks?

Comment: objective-c++ is just as fast as c++. It's the same relationship that objective-c has with c.

Answer (score 1):

You have in fact got two problems to solve here:

- Getting from C++ to Objective-C
- Getting across a thread boundary from the CoreAudio render thread to the UI thread.

Getting from C++ to Objective-C is straightforward: Compile your C++ files as Objective-C++ (rename with a `.mm` extension).

Once you do this, your C++ class can contain a Objective-C object pointer members, and method implementations may send messages to Objective-C objects.  Conversely, your Objective-C++ objects can manage C++ objects and call methods on them.

To get across the thread boundary use Grand Central Dispatch.

```
@interface ObjectiveCBar;

- (void) onVolumeEvent:(float) volume;

@end


class Foo
{
   void notifyUI(float volume)
   {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
            {        
                [objectiveCObject onVolumeEvent:volume];
            });
   }

   ObjectiveCBar     *objectiveCObject;
}
```

You can also de-couple the C++ and Objective-C parts of your code using [NSNotificationCentre](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  To do this, you will need to pass an Objective-C object in the queue

Comment: Thanks for that great reply. I have only one last question that keeps me wondering: Will it change the performance of the code if I rename the cpp to files to mm files without changing the content? I mean just changing the extension. The sound generation, and how I create the vector, is done in c++ and it is working pretty good.

Comment: No. There are no performance issues in doing this, although from an architectural point of view, separating concerns is always a good idea .  You probably want to end up with an architecture which is an C++ - Objective-C++ - Objective-C sandwich.